# How to make text appear in a set position on page when an image is hovered over

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, cell, onmouseover

I've read through similar answers and cant figure out how to edit them to work with my own html. I have a table, and once the mouse hovers over a certain cell in the table text will appear in a white box to the right of the page. If anyone knows how to go about this using Javascript preferably (but anything that works will help) to get this to work that would be great. Here is a snippet of my code for the table, the cell I want to carry out the said event has a `ID="blue1"`.

```
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td id="blue1">
2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
</tr>
```

here is the box I want the text to appear:

```
<div id="whitebox">

<script type= text/javascript>


</script>
</div>
```

This is the text I want to appear in #whitebox once #blue1 is hovered over -

" 2nd Meet John at 2 "

I Have fiddled around with various codes and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to catch [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event and append text with [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```js
$('#blue1').hover(function() {
  $('#whitebox').text('2nd Meet John at 2');
}, function() {
  $('#whitebox').text('whitebox');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="blue1">
      2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="whitebox">
  whitebox
</div>
```

Script could be placed in `<head> ... </head>` section of site using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // script
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please check my edit. Jquery library has to be loaded before script.

Comment: thank you that worked! can you use onMouseOver instead of hover? I want it to disappear once mouse is off my cell

Comment: Please check my edit, you have to use second **.hover()** parameter to put text back.